# Why does this code snippet give segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

This piece of code throws seg fault.Please help me identify the reason for the same

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
        char* str;
        str = "abcd";
        str[0] = 'r';
        printf("%c\n" , str[0]);
        return 0;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well explained in [C FAQ 1.32](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html). It's illegal to modify string literals.

> 6.4.5/6
>
> It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If **the program attempts to
>   modify such an array**, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: thanks for clearing this with detailed explanation and C FAQ is definitely a treasure

Answer (score 3):

```
    str = "abcd";
    str[0] = 'r';
```

This attempts to modify a string literal. Officially, that's undefined behavior. On most modern systems, however, the memory holding string literals will be marked read-only, so attempting to modify them will give a fault.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359340/c-segmentation-fault-when-accessing-a-char-array-index)** related to Segmentation Fault

Refer this for more info.